# On a proof about rational functions and connected components

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-topology

I'm trying to follow a demonstration of the following:

Here $Q$ is a complex function and $S^1$ is the unitary circle.

Let $S = Q^{-1}([-1,1])$ where $Q(z)$ is a rational function of degree at most $2n$ such that $Q(S^1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $S \cap S^1$ has at least $2n$ connected components then $S$ is the union of $2n$ subintervals of $S^1$.

The autor start saying that $Q$ and $Q'$ has degree at most $2n$ and since $Q(S^1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ that must exist at least one zero of $Q'(z)$ in each component of $S^1 - S$, then that is no zero of $Q'(z)$ in $S$, which implies that each connected component of $S \cap S^1$ is mapped diffeomorphically onto [-1,1].

I'm really not familiar with the tool he used here (I'm not even know what kind of theorem he uses on these affirmations), can someone clarify that for me?